# I am seeing a "GET /emp HTTP/1.1" 404 2159 on my terminal when I try to connect to the django server ...I am receiving a 404 page not found

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I feel like my server can't render my views well because of some url configuration issues.It always render the message `Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/emp`

Here is my project structure

```
|--hrdjango
 |--employee
   |--migrations folder
   |--admin.py
   |--urls.py
    ...
   |views.py

|--hrdjango
  ...
 |--settings.py
 |--urls.py
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect  
from .forms import EmployeeForm  
from .models import Employee  
# Create your views here.  
def emp(request):  
    if request.method == "POST":  
        form = EmployeeForm(request.POST)  
        if form.is_valid():  
            try:  
                form.save()  
                return redirect('/show')  
            except:  
                pass  
    else:  
        form = EmployeeForm()  
    return render(request,'index.html',{'form':form}) 
def show(request):  
    employees = Employee.objects.all()  
    return render(request,"show.html",{'employees':employees})  
def edit(request, id):  
    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id)  
    return render(request,'edit.html', {'employee':employee})  
def update(request, id):  
    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id)  
    form = EmployeeForm(request.POST, instance = employee)  
    if form.is_valid():  
        form.save()  
        return redirect("/show")  
    return render(request, 'edit.html', {'employee': employee})  
def destroy(request, id):  
    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id)  
    employee.delete()  
    return redirect("/show")
```

employee/urls.py

```
from .import views  
from django.contrib import admin  
from django.urls import path, include
app_name = 'employee'
urlpatterns = [  
    path('', views.emp, name='emp'),  
    path('show',views.show, name='show'),  
    path('edit/<int:id>', views.edit, name='edit'),  
    path('update/<int:id>', views.update, name='update'),  
    path('delete/<int:id>', views.destroy, name='destroy'),
    ]
```

hrdjango/urls

```
from django.contrib import admin  
from django.urls import include, path
from employee import views  

urlpatterns = [  
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('employee/', include('employee.urls')),
path('', views.emp),
]
```

I was expecting to see the views rendering according to my urls config, but it seems like it can't render my views because it is not seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

You have not any url with this URL pattern `http://127.0.0.1:8000/emp`, instead of that, have you tried e.g with:

1. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`
2. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/show`

Or other URL defined in **employee/urls.py**

Comment: I did  with the firt one I received Type error message the 2nd one gives me page not found messages

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access `emp(request)` view.

## hrdjango/urls

```
from django.contrib import admin  
from django.urls import include, path
from employee import views  

urlpatterns = [  
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('employee/', include('employee.urls')),
    # path('', views.emp), - remove this line
]
```

Then,,, You can make `GET` request for example, like this.

## Below URI will invoke `emp(request)` method

http://127.0.0.1/employee/

Also, in your `ModelForm` `Meta` class, you should specify `Employee` class and not `Employee` class instance.

## forms.py

```
from django import forms 
from .models import Employee 
class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta: 
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'
```

I hope, it helps you.

Comment: ```ValueError at /employee/
ModelForm has no model class specified.``` that's the message I received now.here is my forms.py ```from django import forms  
from .models import Employee  
class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model = Employee()
        fields = "__all__"  ```

Comment: update your question. we do not see you Form/ModelForm implementation.